# how run webservice that run an exe with a dll library in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exe

I am developing a webservice. This webservice execute a .exe called "program.exe". program.exe uses a dll library. When I run program.exe in cmd, it run perfect. The problem is when I try execute program.exe in the webservice.

```
Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(programPath);
                psi.Arguments = "56484864 d:\\ file_kkii.xml";
                p.StartInfo = psi;
                p.Start();
```

When run program.exe in the webservice, it open correctly program.exe, but program.exe fails when it try to use the dll library. The problem is: System.TypeInitializationException

I don't know which is the problem. If I use a Windows server to run the program.exe, the fail is the same.

But If I use the visual studio server to prove it, it run perfect!!

Why it don't work in a webservice and a windowsservice? need I some permission to use the dll?

Thanks for all!

Comment: Do you have the DLL in the same folder as your program.exe?

Comment: I just deleted the other